# Почему "ucfirst()" не работает для русских символов?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте!
У меня часто возникают проблемы с кодировками, в частности с отображением русских символов во всех более-менее современных браузерах. Вот еще один вопрос возник: Почему PHP-функция  **"ucfirst()"** не работает для русских символов? Как можно "заставить" её работать? Или есть хотя бы альтернатива?

**P.S** Только банальщину с заменой букв по массиву предлагать не стоит.

**Спасибо всем, кто откликнулся!**

Answer (score 23, accepted):

UTF-8, разумеется? PHP не может нормально работать с многобайтными кодировками. Наиболее близкое решение:

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
function mb_ucfirst($text) {
    return mb_strtoupper(mb_substr($text, 0, 1)) . mb_substr($text, 1);
}
echo mb_ucfirst("тест\n");
```

На всякий случай, дополню: если вы до сих пор кипятите^W используете CP1251 или, упаси Его Макароннейшество, KOI8-R, то может помочь вызов [`setlocale`](http://php.rinet.ru/setlocale), с однобайтными кодировками `ucfirst` кое-как работает:

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "ru_RU.CP1251");
echo ucfirst("\xf2\xe5\xf1\xf2\n");
```

Но работать это будет только в случае, если в системе есть такая локаль. Т.е. как повезет.

Comment: Спасибо. Отлично все работает. Я вот тоже похожим способом пытался: перевести в верхний регистр первую букву, но не получилось. Еще раз спасибо.

Comment: Да не за что. Вы, наверное, `mb_internal_encoding` забыли когда пробовали — без него используется значение из конфига, а если оно там не задано (что, как правило, и есть), то [творится черт-те что](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49638) и ничего не работает.

Comment: Нет, я конечно же использую ТОЛЬКО "UTF-8". Это есть стандарт.

Comment: Ага, я уже понял, как только созранил и увидел «отлично работает», но не стал стирать. Пусть будет — кто-нибудь еще натолкнется на вопрос потом наверняка.

А CP1251 иногда приходится использовать. Есть такое неприятное явление «поддержка legacy-систем», да. Избранными глухими местами еще KOI8-R стандарт. Правда, это все не в web, обычно.

Answer (score 14):

Если используете utf-8 кодировку, то вам нужна функция [mb_convert_case](http://php.net/mb_convert_case).

Пример:

```
$name = 'ярослав';
echo mb_convert_case($name, MB_CASE_TITLE, "UTF-8"); // Ярослав
```

Comment: Один минус - ставит в верхний регистр первую букву не только первого слова, но и вообще всех слов в строке.

Answer (score 0):

```
$title = 'ASDASDASDASDASD';

$title = mb_strtolower($title, 'UTF-8');

$title = mb_strtoupper(mb_substr($title, 0, 1, 'UTF-8'), 'UTF-8') . mb_substr($title, 1, null,'UTF-8');

echo $title; // 'Asdasdasdasdasd'
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся с подобной проблемой - задача выводить имена пользователей в любой кодировке (кириллице, латинице и др.) из массива с большой буквы. Изобрел такое решение:

```
$names = array("катя", "МАША", "verONIka");

function fix_names($names) {
for ($n = 0; $n < 3; $n++) {
    $names [$n] = mb_strtolower($names[$n]); //все к нижнему регистру
    echo mb_convert_case("$names[$n]", MB_CASE_TITLE, "UTF-8")."\n"; //выводим с первым символом в верхнем регистре
}
} 

fix_names($names); //Катя Маша Veronika
```

Правда не знаю насколько правильно я все сделал, так как новичок и всего неделю изучаю PHP, но тем не менее данный код работает как и требовалось.

Comment: вот так точно не нужно делать работая с PHP: `"$names[$n]"`, просто `$names[$n]` в идеале вообще не использовать синтаксис с двойными кавычками (особенно там где форматирование строк  не нужно), а для форматирования использовать sprintf, работает лучше и спасает от неочевиных багов.