# Как сделать последнюю букву заглавной UTF-8

Tags: php

```
$word = "слово";
```

как сделать:

```
$word = "словО";
```

Comment: `strrev(ucfirst(strrev($word)))`

Comment: @Akina Не работает

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/105911/229437

Comment: @Akina Не работает strrev()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для многобайтовых строк, таких как UTF-8 сущестуют специальные функции:

```
$enc = 'UTF-8';
$word = "слово";
$count = mb_strlen($word, $enc); //Узнаем количество символов в MB строке
$new_word = mb_substr($word, 0, ($count - 1), $enc);
$new_word = $new_word . mb_strtoupper(mb_substr($word,($count - 1), 1, $enc), $enc);
echo $new_word;
```

Результат будет: `словО`.

Функции с приставкой `mb_` учитывают что символы могут быть разного размера.
Например:

```
$str = 'FФ'; //Первый символ латиницей, второй кириллицей

$size = strlen($str);
//Для строки в UTF-8 вернет 3

$size = mb_strlen($str);
//Для строки в UTF-8 вернет 2
```

Это источник многих ошибок для начинающего программиста.

Comment: только нужно учитывать особенности unicode. mb_strlen(Й) == 1, а mb_strlen(Й) == 2 (во втором случае это две кодовые точки - И и диакритический знак Кратка)

Comment: Если необходимо узнать количество "печатных символов" в строке, то необходимо перед `mb_strlen` удалить все диакритические знаки (можно попробовать через `$result = iconv($src_enc, 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $str))`;

Answer (score -3):

```
$str = "привет мир";  
$last = strlen($str)-1;
list($str[$last-1], $str[$last]) = mb_strtoupper($str[$last-1].$str[$last], 'UTF8');  
echo $str;
```

Comment: strlen не учитывает UTF-8. Вы получите ошибку с большой вероятностью.

Comment: mad Jerico Пожалуйста, не переходите на личности. Поставил флаг на комментарии. Ответу кстати минус - он действительно неправильный.

Comment: вопрос платформы..