# Первая буква строки в нижний регистр (Кириллица)

Tags: php

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как перевести первую букву строки в нижний регистр в Кириллице?

Comment: `mb_strtolower("Тест");`?

Comment: В данном случае вся строка переводится в нижний регистр, а нужно лишь первую букву.

Comment: См. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/105908/Почему-ucfirst-не-работает-для-русских-символов

Comment: К сожалению, не подходит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отделяем первый символ от остального текста и приводим к нижнему регистру, затем присоединяем его обратно.

```
$value = 'Родился на улице Герцена, в гастрономе номер двадцать два.';
$value .= ' Известный экономист, по призванию своему — библиотекарь.';

$firstChar = mb_substr($value, 0, 1);
$firstChar = mb_strtolower($firstChar);
$otherChars = mb_substr(
    $value,
    1,
    mb_strlen($value)
);

$value = $firstChar . $otherChars;
```

Более стильный вариант в виде функции, пользуйтесь на здоровье.

```
function firstCharToLowercase(string $value): string
{
    $firstChar = mb_substr($value, 0, 1);
    $firstChar = mb_strtolower($firstChar);
    $otherChars = mb_substr(
        $value,
        1,
        mb_strlen($value)
    );

    return $firstChar . $otherChars;
}
```

Comment: Если возникнут проблемы с кодировкой, напишите и мы что-нибудь придумаем.

Comment: В версии PHP 5.6 возникает синтаксическая ошибка: PHP Syntax Check: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '{' in your code on line 1

Comment: Просто удалите тайп-хинты из первой строки:
function firstCharToLowercase($value)
{}