# Замена первой буквы в строке на заглавную

Tags: php

Нужно заменить первую букву на любом языке в строке на заглавную, а остальные оставить в нижнем регистре, перепробовал уже всё, что мог и понимаю, что только через регулярные выражения возможно выполнить это.

Что бы я не делал, вылетает ошибка или выводится пустая строка.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/105908/Почему-ucfirst-не-работает-для-русских-символов. Никакие регулярные выражения тут не нужны. Умение гуглить нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял то вот один из вариантов:

```
$data = 'slovo';
echo mb_convert_case($data, MB_CASE_TITLE, "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

Предыдущий вариант не совсем верен. Он переводит в верхний регистр первую букву КАЖДОГО слова в строке. А по условиям задачи нужно только первую букву в строке.

```php
$str = 'Ваша строка на любом языке';
echo mb_convert_case(mb_substr($str, 0, 1), MB_CASE_UPPER, "UTF-8").mb_convert_case(mb_substr($str, 1, mb_strlen($str) -1 ), MB_CASE_LOWER, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: так и ваш не верен. в отличие от соседнего он весь остаток строки к нижнему регистру приводит, а об этом не просили.

Comment: @teran - `первую букву на любом языке в строке на заглавную, а остальные оставить в нижнем регистре`

Comment: и действительно, упустил. но думаю высока вероятно, что надо остальное не в нижний регистр перевести, а оставить как есть.

Answer (score 0):

А что не так с функцией ucfirst? Работает начиная с 4 версии.

```
<?php
$foo = 'hello world!';
$foo = ucfirst($foo); // Hello world!
```

Ссылка на официальную документацию: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.ucfirst.php

Comment: `$foo = 'а что не так с функцией ucfirst?';
echo  ucfirst($foo); // ???`

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = 'Ваша строка на любом языке';
echo mb_convert_case(mb_substr($str, 0, 1), MB_CASE_UPPER, "UTF-8").mb_convert_case(mb_substr($str, 1, mb_strlen($str) -1 ), MB_CASE_LOWER, "UTF-8");
```

Очень интересный, у меня не работает mb_string, поэтому и задал вопрос.
Оказывается я неправильно юзал ucfirst и ничего не выдавало.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).